# Can I install and use Ionic Native in a cordova project?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-native

In this project I only use cordova 9 and angular 7 and not Ionic installed. 
But I want to use cordova plugins and I know  Ionic Native wrap these plugins for use observes in angular
Is mandatory install Ionic first?

In that case, must I unistall cordova or can live together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer **Yes**.

As stated on their Website

Ionic Native is a library of Cordova plugins and integrations that make it easy to add native functionality to any Ionic app, Cordova project, or WebView. Ionic Native is available in two editions: Community and Enterprise.

Suppose you want to use ionic-native/Camera

// app.module.ts

```
import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx';

...
@NgModule({
  ...

  providers: [
    ...
    Camera
    ...
  ]
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

After the plugin has been declared, it can be imported and injected like any other service:

```
// camera.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PhotoService {
  constructor(private camera: Camera) { }

  takePicture() {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
      quality: 100,
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
      mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
    }

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
      // Do something with the new photo

    }, (err) => {
     // Handle error
     console.log("Camera issue: " + err);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ionic native is for ionic projects.
start a new ionic project and use ionic native and cordova plugins in it.

Comment: Thank you for you answer

Answer (score 0):

yes first you have to install `IONIC` and you can lie with `cordova`

> https://ionicframework.com/docs/intro

```
npm install -g ionic cordova
```

then make your Project

```
ionic start helloWorld blank --type=ionic-angular
```